# How do I define an Enum as a global entity?

Tags: apex

I have a set of enums that needs to be used by a number of classes?

Do I define each of them in their own class?  What is the accepted practice.  For instance...

```
public class Proposal {
    OrderTypeEnum orderType {get; set;}
    ProposalStatus proposalStatus {get; set;}
}

public class Order {
    OrderTypeEnum orderType {get; set;}
}

public enum OrderType
{
    Coop = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    Package = 2,
    SubInvoicing = 3,
}

public enum ProposalStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Won = 1,
    Lost = 2,
    Canceled = 3,
}
```

Do all these entities need to be defined in their own .cls file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate class files are not required per enum.

```
public without sharing class Foo {  
    public   enum  Bar      { BAR1, BAR2 }
    public   enum  Fie      { FIE1, FIE2 }
}
```

Reference in other classes by notation Foo.Bar.BAR1 or Foo.Fie.FIE1

Comment: I guess, I wanted to access it by simply saying `Bar.BAR1` or `Fie.FIE1` without the `Foo` class.  Is that possible?

Comment: Others may have a different answer (and I'd be grateful to know) but I believe if you want to do Bar.BAR1 you will need a class Bar and thus, a separate class Fie.  I used to do the separate class route and decided that fewer classes was better than the extra characters in the reference